# Entity Framework - Wrong query result for case-sensitive value

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a simple query like image below. The problem is when I query by lowercase value, it still returns a Uppercase value for me. I am confusing with EF now.
Can someone give a hint about that one.
[image]

I want to get only data with Category = "S3_BUCKET_name" not Category = "S3_BUCKET_NAME"

Comment: This may be in case of using case-insensitive db (SQL Server, MySql), so you nee to use case-sensitive collation in for your db schema. For example for SQL server, use EF migrations:  in OnModelCreating of your dbcontext  apply modelBuilder.UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS"); Or you can change collation fo specific column modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(c => c.Name)
    .UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

Comment: It depends on the db settings, which you use below.

You have several possible solutions.

I personally would change the settings of the column, that you want it to be "case sensitive".

Comment: Oh thank you.I knew problem. Default collation of Mysql is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and it is case-insensitive. So I have to change case-sensitive collation like utf8mb4_0900_as_cs